# Couldn't remove a single quotes from a string?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

This is my string:

```
String str = "CREATE TABLE `patiant` (  `ID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,  `PATIANT_NAME`...";
```

I tried using `replace` and `replaceAll` methods but didn't work.

Here you can see what I'v tried I don't know why it's not working:

1. `temp = str.replace("'","");`
2. `temp = str.replaceAll("(^')","");`

How to remove *all* quotes from the string?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to remove back quotes you have to say so in your code.  You can't remove any symbol which looks like a single quote and expect it to know what you meant to happen.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Thanks,Sorry I didn't mentioned it, in fact I didn't know it's back quotes rather than a single quote, if I recognized it I would't ask the question:).

Comment: Sometimes which I don't know what character I am looking at I use copy and paste, into the code. ;)

Comment: That's really a nice trick way :D

Comment: You would be amazed what characters you might come across. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/hidden-code.html

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I am amazed, actually I am amazed and laughing :D

Comment: Like these smiley faces... http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/uses-for-special-characters-in-java-code.html

Comment: @AzadOmer BTW, you might want to know it's spelt "patient" not "patiant" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your quotes are [grave accents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) (`), so you are replacing the wrong type of quote.  So try this instead:

```
temp = str.replaceAll("`","");
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not a plain back tick or back quote?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Sorry, not sure what you mean - a grave accent is a backtick if that's what you meant.

Comment: Sorry, I found the terminology confusing as à, è, ì, ò, ù all have grave accents, but your find and replace won't touch those.

Answer (score 1):

The input `String` contains backticks rather than single quotes so these need to be replaced rather than the latter:

Either

```
temp = str.replace("`", "");
```

or

```
temp = str.replaceAll("`", "");
```

will perform the replacement correctly

Answer (score 0):

here the code so you can prove rigth now:

---

```
public class TestMain {

public TestMain() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "CREATE TABLE `patiant` (  `ID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,  `PATIANT_NAME`...";
    String new_string_remplace = str.replaceAll("`",""); 
    System.out.println(new_string_remplace);
    //RESULT: CREATE TABLE patiant (  ID varchar(45) NOT NULL,  PATIANT_NAME...

}

}
```

Note: the replace String java.lang.String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement).

Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

An invocation of this method of the form str.replaceAll(regex, repl) yields exactly the same result as the expression